# Pause JQuery sequence until all iframes are loaded

Tags: jquery

Simple question I believe, but I am unable to figure how can I do that?

```
m.find("iframe[src=''][data-src]").each(function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
        // something here
    }).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
});
// how to pause here until all 'load's are fired?
m.css("visibility", "visible");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var el = m.find("iframe[src][data-src]")
, len = el.length
, t = 0;
el.each(function () {
    $(this).load(function (e) {
        ++t;
        if (t === len) {
            el.css("visibility", "visible")
        }
    }).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/1mz29r9u/

Answer (score 1):

Here is something based on a method I have used. You'll probably want to add more error handling for in case an iframe doesn't load or there aren't any iframes (if that is possible.)

```
var deferred = $.Deferred(),
    $iframes = m.find("iframe[src=''][data-src]"),
    count = $iframes.length;

$iframes.each(function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
        // something here
        if(--count == 0) {
           deferred.resolve(); // We have received all the expected loads
        }
    }).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
});

deferred.promise().done(function() {
                            m.css("visibility", "visible");
                        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the .stop() function!